# Can I deploy apps to Blackberry devices without signing?

Tags: blackberry

Is it necessary to sign apps before deploying them to devices? Isn't there a workaround where we can deploy apps without signing?

Comment: signing keys are free these days, no reason to not sign

Comment: @ber4444 I know signing keys are free, but during development phase it more of a trouble especially when you are debugging a problem.

Comment: sure the signing server is sometimes down but otherwise it's a piece of cake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to run an unsigned application on actual device, only if you did not use "signed API" classes.

In RIM API javadoc for every class there is information, does it belong to signed API or not.

For instance, [Bitmap](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html) does not belong to "signed API".

But [Display](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html) class does.

Excerpt from `Display` class description:

*Signed: This element is only accessible by signed clients. If you intend to use this element, please contact RIM to establish the necessary agreements that will allow you to have your COD files signed. Signing is only required for use on the device, development under the JDE can occur without signing the CODs.*